# JHipster Microservices with Oauth2 + JWT

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, jhipster, okta

I have created 2 JHipster applications (JHipster v6.3.1):

Microservice Gateway
authenticationType: oauth2

Microservice Application
authenticationType: jwt

I have configured Okta with the gateway app and this works fine, I can log in with my user. I can also see that the ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER authorities are being correctly assigned in Spring Security.

However I get the following error from the Microservice Application when I attempt to add/view an entity:

Unsupported JWT token.
Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Is there some configuration I need to do to get the JWT token passed in to the Microservice Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix authentication types between microservice apps. You have to use either OAuth 2.0 or JWT in all of them. FWIW, JHipster's OAuth 2.0 support does use JWTs.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I am using some config in the application.yml for Okta. Should I add this to both the gateway and the microservice app?

Comment: Yes. Or you can use Spring Cloud Config in JHipster Registry to configure them all. This tutorial has more information about how to do that. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/23/java-microservices-spring-cloud-config

Comment: Thanks. In my case the microservice and gateway applications were running in oauth2 (Okta config), but the JHipster Registry was still running in default authentication type. I updated the registry bootstrap.yml to use the oauth2 profile and added the Okta settings in application-oauth2.yml. Working now.